# Billing fields not prepopulated by PayPal SDK

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I am using the PayPal Merchant .NET SDK http://paypal.github.io/sdk/ to implement Express Checkout.

The code snippet bellow is for my SetExpressCheckout call.  The only field that gets pre-populated is the email address.  Does anyone know the right way to do this?  BTW - the PayPal billing screen has First and Last name fields but the API only has a name field???

```
SetExpressCheckoutRequestType request = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType ecDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
...
ecDetails.ReqConfirmShipping = "0";
ecDetails.NoShipping = "1";
ecDetails.AddressOverride = "1";
ecDetails.SolutionType = SolutionTypeType.SOLE;
PaymentDetailsType paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
CurrencyCodeType currency = CurrencyCodeType.USD;
paymentDetails.OrderDescription = "Test";
paymentDetails.OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType(currency, "1.00");
ecDetails.PaymentDetails.Add(paymentDetails);
ecDetails.PaymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.SALE;
ecDetails.LandingPage = LandingPageType.BILLING;
ecDetails.BuyerEmail = "bob@smith.com";
AddressType address = new AddressType();
address.Name = "Bob";
address.Street1 = "123 somewhere st";
address.Street2 = "#32";
address.CityName = "Houston";
address.StateOrProvince = "TX";
address.PostalCode = "12345";
address.CountryName = "US";
address.Phone = "123-456-7890";
ecDetails.BillingAddress = address;
request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = ecDetails;
```

I've played around with the first 3 settings shown and have it doesn't seem to help.  The email is populated and the order description is fine.  Country is set based on my test account and not the address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

**ADDROVERRIDE**
(Optional) Determines whether or not the PayPal pages should display the shipping address set by you in this SetExpressCheckout request, not the shipping address on file with PayPal for this buyer. Displaying the PayPal street address on file does not allow the buyer to edit that address. It is one of the following values:

0 – The PayPal pages should not display the shipping address.

1 – The PayPal pages should display the shipping address.

Character length and limitations: 1 single-byte numeric character.

Use `ecDetails.AddressOverride = 1;` as the .NET SDK version of this.

Also you need to set `paymentDetails.ShipToAddress` instead of `ecDetails.BillingAddress` filling out the billing address requires `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME` etc fields to be set. Which means your first `ecDetails.PaymentDetails` must have the address associated with it.

For setting the users name it is a string that would be `address.Name = "Bob Smith";`

Comment: Also note, this does set the billing and shipping address for "Guest Checkout." However, the user will be able to change the billing address but NOT the shipping address.

Comment: Thanks but this did not work.  I'm trying to set the billing address not the shipping address.

Comment: Can you try setting `paymentDetails.ShipToAddress` instead of `ecDetails.BillingAddress` I was able to get the Billing Address to fill out, but it requires `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME` etc fields to be set. Which means your first `ecDetails.PaymentDetails` must have the address associated with it.

Comment: Yes that was the solution.  I had to specify a shipping address even though I'm not displaying it, and then the billing address showed up.  That ought to be documented somewhere.  If you put that answer into an answer I will mark it as the correct answer.  Thanks

Comment: I would like to point out that now the PayPal checkout Review page shows a Shipping Address.  This checkout is for a donation, their is no Shipping involved.  Not an ideal solution.